# Jedis broken pipe exception

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I use Redis for authentication in servlet filter, and I haven't modified **redis.conf**

```
jedis = new Jedis("localhost");
String authToken = jedis.get(uid);
```

Line 2 throws an exception.

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
redis.clients.jedis.Connection.flush(Connection.java:291)
redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBinaryBulkReply(Connection.java:214)
redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBulkReply(Connection.java:205)
redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.get(Jedis.java:105)
filter.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:38)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 3):

The connection seems to be reset/disconnected. This can happen when you use a long-living connection (e. g. connect to Redis on application start and then use the connection over and over).

Possible solutions are:

1. Use `JedisPool` to obtain a connection when needed and return it after using it
2. Reconnect if the connection is broken (needs some try/catch magic to prevent that errors are propagated to your application logic)
3. Connect at the moment you need the connection and disconnect afterwards

There are also Java Redis Clients that provide transparent reconnect meaning you won't ever see a socket exception ([lettuce](https://github.com/mp911de/lettuce), [redisson](https://github.com/mrniko/redisson)).